# iOS 8 - UILabel doesn't update until a touch/scroll event is registered

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have several `UILabel`s embedded in a `UITableView`. The problem is that the label text is not being updated/rendered unless the table row is touched/selected by the user.

I've read other forum posts which say the code for updating the label should be enclosed in a `dispatch_async` and the `setNeedsDisplay` called as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() { 
    self.mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.object.T];
    [self.mylabel setNeedsDisplay]; 
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working for me. I am certain that all storyboard connections have all been done correction. Again just to clarify, the label updates do seem to be working but do not to render on screen until the user touches the corresponding table row.

This is quite frustrating as apart from this bug, my app is ready for submission! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> Again just to clarify, the label updates do seem to be working but do
>   not to render on screen until the user touches the corresponding table
>   row.

That certainly indicates that you're doing some UI work from a background thread. But before just wrapping your `-setText:` call in a `dispatch_async`, I'd check in the debugger that you are in fact calling it in a background thread. If you're not, that code isn't going to help. It could be you're doing some other UI work from a background thread, and this is just a casualty. And the `-setNeedsDisplay` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response. All the UI stuff takes place in the viewDidLoad method of the relevant view controller. I can't make sense of the debug pane - there are multiple threads running but I can't tell which actual function/method is responsible for each thread.

Comment: Yes, a screenshot of the debug screen when it hits your -setText: command might help.

Comment: I've just tried but unfortunately I don't have a high enough reputation count to upload pictures.

Comment: Stick it in your Dropbox and add a link to it here in the comments.